Maximo Automation Script for POST Integration - JSON - PYTHON
I'm writing to write automation script for integration to post status change from Maximo to external rest api
from java.lang import String
from java.util import HashMap
from psdi.iface.router import HTTPHandler
from com.ibm.json.java import JSON

url = "https://xxx.xxx.ae:443/ws/T/1.0/notify"

payload = {
  "Record": {
    "ProviderCode": "XXX",
    "ApplicationWorkflowID": "1",
    "ProviderStatusNameArabic": "مكتمل",
    "ProviderStatusNameEnglish": "Completed",
    "StatusDate": "2024-03-19T12:11:21.2330009+04:00",
    "StatusUpdateRefCode": "3126",
    "StatusUpdateRefKey": {
      "Field": {
        "FieldName": "Refkey",
        "FieldValue": "SR-196191"
      }
    },
    "NotificationCommentArabic": "Approved",
    "NotificationCommentEnglish": "Approved",
    "NotificationRelatedParties": {
      "Party": {
        "PartyEmirateID": "1234567",
        "PartyExtraInfo": {
          "Field": [
            {
              "FieldName": "NotificationReasonTitle_EN",
              "FieldValue": "Completed"
            },
            {
              "FieldName": "NotificationReasonTitle_AR",
              "FieldValue": "تم"
            },
            {
              "FieldName": "NotificationReason_EN",
              "FieldValue": "Approved"
            },
            {
              "FieldName": "NotificationReason_AR",
              "FieldValue": "تم"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "NotificationStatusCode": "Completed",
    "NotificationAction": "UPDATE"
  }
}
headers = {
  'x-CentraSite-APIKey': 'eeexxxxxx',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': '0fff39cb-e988-4848-84fc-e24178a2c684=68cb189ffab33796890929ba33c927ec; TS014a97b0=018666c34ac2cdb50e6a16e102803dc1d9ed5c9cfcfae70e1cad9c479814b07b20e41be341bb7aebdff7614169bcf14c6cfd3128fd5e69bcd4e913be68ce60c41d7cc8a21d'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

but I got error from Maximo "BMXAA7837E - An error occured that prevented the TEST2 script for the TESTINT launch point from running.
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined in  at line number 59"
Thank you.
but I got error from Maximo "BMXAA7837E - An error occured that prevented the TEST2 script for the TESTINT launch point from running.
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined in  at line number 59"
